# Any way to override path traversal protection in unzip?

Tags: rhel, zip

When you try to unzip a file with relative paths above the working directory (e.g. `../../foo`), you get this message:

```
warning: skipped "../" path component(s) in ../../foo

inflating: foo
```

The issue is, our software is creating these zips with relative paths during an installation, and if the installation goes wrong, we unzip them to put everything back the way it was.  If the user has elected to store some data files "above" the normal installation directory, we end up with `../datafile` in the backup.  This should be perfectly fine, and we want unzip to trust the archive and put the files back if we ask.  Unfortunately, I can't find an option to tell `unzip` to not worry about the `../` path components and unzip the archive exactly as it was created.  Is there an option to unzip to do this?

Note that changing the way the zips are created is not possible at this time, so "Don't do it that way" is not an acceptable answer.  We've got to play the hand we've been given.  The target platform is RHEL 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do what you're asking for

```
unzip -: foo.zip
```

From the man page

> -:     [all  but  Acorn, VM/CMS, MVS, Tandem] allows to extract archive
>             members into locations outside of the current '' extraction root
>             folder''.  For security reasons, unzip normally removes ''parent
>             dir'' path components (''../'')  from  the  names  of  extracted
>             file.  This safety feature (new for version 5.50) prevents unzip
>             from accidentally writing files to ''sensitive''  areas  outside
>             the  active  extraction  folder  tree  head.  The -: option lets
>             unzip switch back to its previous, more  liberal  behaviour,  to
>             allow  exact  extraction  of  (older) archives that used ''../''
>             components to create multiple directory trees at  the  level  of
>             the  current  extraction  folder.   This  option does not enable
>             writing explicitly to the root directory  (''/'').   To  achieve
>             this,  it  is  necessary  to set the extraction target folder to
>             root (e.g. -d / ).  However, when the -: option is specified, it
>             is  still  possible to implicitly write to the root directory by
>             specifiying  enough  ''../''  path  components  within  the  zip
>             archive.  Use this option with extreme caution.

Comment: Perfect!  I verified that this does exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: For the record, I *did* check the man page... I just missed this. :-)

Comment: @BillHayden I almost missed it too. The non-letter based flags always trip me up.